# Escaping URL for stylesheet & W3C validation

Tags: php, css

I have a dynamic stylesheet in which I need to provide some GET variables to a PHP page, and using .htaccess, it is rewritten as .css. The way it is referenced in the `<head>` of the page is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/min.css?style=testing&layout=flat&ver=0.1">
```

The problem is when I run it through the W3C validator, it says it's invalid code and the URL needs escaped. But, when I escape it like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/min.css?style=testing&amp;layout=flat&amp;ver=0.1">
```

The stylesheet is not read properly.

What can I do to make this valid code and work at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some solutions that pop into mind:

1) Use only one parameter in url.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/min.css?style=testing_flat_0.1">
```

2) use a minification library like Minify (it's in php), which it will return a url like *this [http://www.example.com/?css=70385ee2be4c63d0932eeb51baa1e5af](http://www.example.com/?css=70385ee2be4c63d0932eeb51baa1e5af_)* after you feed it with the desired css files you want it to minfy  - https://github.com/mrclay/minify.

3) Use a service like grunt (https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin) to minify and have it return a w3c valid url.

4) If you are using a framework for your apllication, try its url routing capabilities. So you can ask for your css file like this for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/testing/css/0.1/min.css">
```